# How to show daily orders in the calendar grid view using php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for any demo solution and any help with 'Day Grid View Calendar'.

I want to show daily orders on the calendar. So the calendar must be in daily grid view. I will have PHP loop display data on the calendar.

Is this possible?

I cannot find any examples online or find any resources.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Judging by this question, you may not be completely clear on how to best use this site. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [ask] a good question sections to see what questions are on and off topic, to see how this site works and to help you improve your future questions, which can help you get a better reception from site members and perhaps decent answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/)?
It's free, [open source](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar), and easy to use.